# D3 problem on placing a circle on area

Tags: d3

I am using d3.
I normally constructed d3.svg.area().interpolate("basis")
then I want to put a circle on outline of the area. But,
because of  interpolate("basis"). The outline is not
at exact place. So, I can't place circle on
outline of the area.

Do you have any idea about how I can solve the problem ?

Comment: When I changed interpolation to ' monotone' it looks OK.